# Setting driver path dynamically for Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have have a test that needs to be ran against IE,CEFmp and Chrome. Requirement are as follows:

1. Should be one single conf.js for IE,Cefmp and Chrome
2. Should read browser type from a file and run the test against that particular browser.
3. For Chrome and CEFmp runs,direct connect should be true
4. For Chrome and CEFmp runs, should only pick up specific driver given in local path not from protractor default path.

I was able to pick specific browser type based on value mentioned in the file and run test against it along with setting direct connect to true for Chrome and CEFmp browser types.
How ever, I am unable to find a solution for making the test pick up a specific Chrome driver. For now its picking the default driver given in node_modules/protractor/selenium and running the test with it. I would like to know if there is a way to pick driver in specific path dynamically?

Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should:

- set more values in your text file, like "chrome-x", "chrome-y"
- add a "webdrivers" folder in your projet
- store chromedrivers in it (every versions you need)

Then, in your code:

```
File chromeDriverFile = new File("webdrivers/" + webdriverAsRetrievedInYourTextFile); // you define the path here
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverFile.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. How can this be done for protractor?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I found a `kind-of` solution for this problem. If there is better way to do it please do let me know.

As I was not able to find a way to redirect the path to the driver for picking it from the local folder, so one way we solved it was by copy and replace the default location driver(node_module) with the local driver(one we want to use) by doing this

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname + '/bin/Drivers/CefMp/chromedriver.exe')).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.resolve('C:/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver.exe')));
```

So in this way, even though `protractor` picks the default driver from `node_modules` folder it will end up using the driver we want it to use.